# PHP array to count and return index of similar value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alex
    [1] => Michael
    [2] => Harry
    [3] => Dave
    [4] => Michael
    [5] => Victor
    [6] => Harry
    [7] => Alex
    [8] => Mary
    [9] => Mary
)
```

I want to write a PHP function to count the number of time a value is repeated and only give me the value that is repeated maximum number of time. Below is my code

```
function writeIn($ballot) {

    foreach($ballot as $b) {
        $arr[] = $b;
    }

    print_r($arr);

}
```

Comment: `foreach ($ballot as $index => $name){ $counted[$name] = isset($counted[$name]? $counted[$name] + 1 : 1;}`

Answer (score 1):

[`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) was made for this:

```
function writeIn($ballot) {
    $counts = array_count_values($ballot);
    $max = array_search(max($counts), $counts, true);
    print_r($max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to return an array of names, so get the highest vote count with `array_count_values()` and then loop through and push each name with that many votes into a returned array:

```
function writeIn($ballot) {
    $results = array_count_values($ballot);
    foreach($results as $key => $value){
        if(max($results) === $value){
            $top[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $top;
}

print_r(writeIn($arr));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alex
    [1] => Michael
    [2] => Harry
    [3] => Mary
)
```